# How to store/communicate global asynchronous data to controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

The basic premise is this....

I have an application. When the user hits the application, it immediately fetches various information regarding the user from a sharepoint server through an ajax call. And depending on what kind of data is received from the user, the app has to display/hide certain information and set certain settings.

Each controller within the application is heavily dependent on the data that is returned from this sharepoint server.

I have several questions...

**First**, where should this ajax call be made? Ideally it should be run as soon as possible, so should it be executed in the `app.run()`?

**Second**, where should this data that gets returned from the sharepoint server be stored? I read that making a factory for the sole purpose of storing data is not best practice, and it is better to just use the `$rootscope`. Right now, I am just storing a `User` object in a factory call `"User"` which in hindsight I guess is a no no

**Finally**, I'm not sure if there is a way to suspend the loading of the controllers as they are heavily dependent on this on the data that gets returned, but if there isn't, how would one communicate the information that gets received to the controllers.  Would this be a case to use the `$broadcast` method?

Right now I have a kind of hackish solution. It gets the job done, but I'm pretty sure it is less than ideal

Here is a part of one controller. I am injecting the factory User into it

```
if (User.HasLoadedUserProps == false)
{
    User.registerObserverCallback(hasLoadedProperties);
    User.GetUser("1111");
}
else
{
    if (User.IsAdmin == true)
        //do whatever
}
```

Once the necessary information has been returned from the ajax call, it calls this

```
var hasLoadedProperties = function ()
{
    if (User.IsAdmin == true)
        //do whatever
    else
        utilities.popupBox("You do not have permission to view this page", "Access Denied");
}
```

Any wisdom, insight, or advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First:**

When your ajax call should happen depends on a few things, but since you mention that you'd like to defer controller loading until the user data is pulled down, your best bet is to put the call in your service. More on that in my response to your last item. Placing that data in a service also makes it easier to share across controllers, which brings us to the next point...

**Second:**

Your user data absolutely *should* go in a service, and absolutely *should not* go in `$rootScope`. Think of `$rootScope` like you do `window` / globals in JavaScript. You want to avoid using it for much of anything. An exception would be where you really, really need to use events (`$broadcast`/`$emit`/`$on`) but even those cases should be rare.

**Finally:**

Look into the `resolve` option for [`$routeProvider`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/%24routeProvider) (there are similar options for [`ui-router`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) if you prefer that route (no pun intended).

This option allows you to defer the instantiation of a controller until a set of promises is resolved. In your case, you should return a promise from your `User` service, which is resolved once the user data is retrieved.

To help demonstrate these points, I made this [simple demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/7Gixoa1f4NwZGGamsmEG?p=preview). This code, along with the links to the Angular docs, should be enough to get you going ...

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'beer.html',
    controller: 'BeerController',
    resolve: {
      beer: function(Beer){ //injected into controller once promise is resolved
        return Beer.getFavorite();
      }
    }
  })
})
.controller('BeerController', function($scope, beer) { // Will load after 3s
  $scope.favoriteBeer = beer; // beer comes from resolve in $routeProvider
})
.factory('Beer', function($timeout) {
  var beer = {
    favorite: 'porter'
  };

  beer.getFavorite = function() {
    return $timeout(function() { // pretend this is an ajax call
      return beer.favorite;
    }, 3000);
  }

  return beer;
});
```

...where `beer.html` contains:

```
<div>
  My favorite kind of beer is: {{favoriteBeer}}
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for this. definitely got me on the right track